# Upload IPA to iTunes Connect from a different Mac

Tags: app-store, application-loader

I would just like to confirm my understanding and check whether it can be done or not. I have an iMac and a Macbook for development. I have created an IPA for the app store which I need to upload it to iTunes.

Now my question is that I have generated the IPA from the iMac which contains all the profiles and certificates. Can I upload the IPA from the Macbook using Application Loader 3.0, but the Macbook does not contain any of the profiles and certificates.

From my understanding it should be doable as the IPA contains everything required, but still wants to confirm with other developers in the community.

Comment: To add more details to the question the iMac has al the certificates and profiles required to generate the app store distribution IPA. But I want to upload the IPA from the Macbook which only has Application loader and not the certificates and profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done and Application Loader has no dependency on the certificates and profiles. We just need to login using the proper credential and then select the proper IPA which is required to be uploaded.